# how to resolve merge conflicts between non-code files

Tags: unity, git

While working with my team, we often work on same prefabs and have merge conflicts. Usually, we avoid this as much as possible by trying to work on the asset isolated, but, it seems hard to avoid, and we have resolved it by repeating some hours of work by doing either of `git checkout --ours ...` or `git checkout --theirs ...`.

Is this the only way to resolve merge conflict between non-code files? What are other methods of handling them? How do devs usually solve merge conflict between non-code files? like .prefabs, or .unity files ? Does unity or any library for unity provide tools to solve this sort of merge conflicts?

Comment: Unity includes a setting to force all project files to use a text-based format, rather than binary. You may find that helps considerably with source control (but it doesn't address any non-unity files). See Asset Serialisation mode here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-EditorManager.html